# How to use queues with "with" context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I'm currently trying to create a context manager with queues.

```
import contextlib
import queue
import random
import time
from threading import Thread

import requests
from loguru import logger

list_op_proxy = [
    "http://test.io:12345",
    "http://test.io:123456",
]

proxy_q = queue.Queue()

for i in list_op_proxy:
    proxy_q.put(i)

session = requests.Session()


class QueuePut(contextlib.AbstractContextManager):

    def __enter__(self):
        self.proxy = proxy_q.get(block=True)
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, excType, excValue, traceback):
        proxy_q.put(self.proxy)


def handler(name):
    while True:
        with QueuePut() as proxy:
            try:
                session.proxies = {
                    'https': f'http://{proxy}'
                }
                logger.info(f"{name} | Proxy in use: {proxy}")

                with session.get("https://stackoverflow.com"):
                    logger.info(f"{name} - Yay request made!")

                time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))

            except requests.RequestException as err:
                logger.debug(f"Error! Lets try again! {err}")
                continue

            except Exception as err:
                logger.exception(f"Error! Lets debug! {err}")
                raise Exception from err

for i in range(5):
    Thread(target=handler, args=(f'Thread {i}',)).start()
```

I believe by having a class for QueuePut and threads that shares among the queue, I do believe that whenever we use the `__enter__`it replaces self.proxy to the latest proxy that has been accessing the `__enter__` method which I do believe that could be an issue where we might get a proxy lost back to the queue.

What I am trying to achieve is that when we call the QueuePut, it should take the proxy from the queue, use it in our handler() and whenever if we get an exception or successful requests. It should "automatically" add back the proxy back to the queue.

How am I able to do that using context manager with queues?

Edit after the comments:

```
2021-07-07 12:34:00.952 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 0 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:00.952 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 1 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:03.211 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB593A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:03.211 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 2 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:05.465 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:05.465 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 1 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:07.718 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:07.719 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 4 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:09.973 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:09.973 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 1 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:12.227 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59A90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:12.227 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 4 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:14.479 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB595B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:14.480 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 1 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:16.733 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB598E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:16.733 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 4 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:18.986 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB599A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:18.987 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 1 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:21.241 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB598B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:21.241 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 4 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:23.493 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:23.494 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 0 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:25.747 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:25.748 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 3 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:28.000 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:28.000 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 0 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
2021-07-07 12:34:30.253 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB598B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:30.253 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 1 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:12345
2021-07-07 12:34:32.507 | INFO     | __main__:handler:49 - Error! Lets try again! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BD1CB59490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
2021-07-07 12:34:32.507 | INFO     | __main__:handler:41 - Thread 0 | Proxy in use: http://test.io:123456
```

Comment: It should be `session.proxies = { 'http':  f'http://{proxy}' }`. (You had 'https'). Other than that, it looks OK.

Comment: @Booboo Ahhh, that is true. But really? Is it actually good? I thought by declaring the value `self.proxy = proxy_q.get(block=True)` and then use it in the `__exit__` could cause an issue where it might not put back the correct value.

Comment: Actually, I meant: `session.proxies = { 'http':  proxy }`.  Why wouldn't it put back the correct value? It's putting back the value it got from the queue and saved as self.proxy.

Comment: @Booboo Right, so I thought if I have 5 threads that is running simultaneously, if thread 1 ask for queue.get and places the value to self.proxy and thread 2 now ask for queue.get and sets the self.proxy, wouldn't that replace the previous self.proxy th en?

Comment: Each thread is doing `with QueuePut() ...`.  and so they are creating *their own instance* of `QueuePut` and will therefore each have their own copy of `self.proxy`.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! Then yes! Working as I expected then I would say! then I believe I have another issue then, Looks like the example I have given, As soon as thread 0 finished, instead of thread 2 to pick it up the next queue, looks like the thread 0 takes it again. What do you think is the cause of it?

Comment: You can't control how threads are scheduled, especially when each thread is sleeping a random amount of time!

Comment: But it never reaches the sleep since it cannot reach to the proxy server so it throws exeception at `except requests.RequestException as err:` which do not have a sleep. @Booboo

Comment: Are you saying that thread 0 is getting the same exact proxy twice in a row with no other threads running in between?

Comment: @Booboo Correct, see the edited question (Refresh the page) I have uploaded the output when I execute the script. Even though I have 5 threads running, the threads 2-4 never gets executed by getting a queue.get (Like it is too slow to get)

Comment: I am not familiar with `loguru` and I don't know what the logging level is set at. It might be possible that not all logging requests are being output such as `logger.debug(f"Error! Lets try again! {err}")` and so you are not logging *all* the actual requests and you might have missed a proxy being used and released. Change this to `logger.info` or `logger.error`.

Comment: @Booboo I tried one thing and that is to remove the `logger.debug(f"Error! Lets try again! {err}")` totally. by just having ```except requests.RequestException as err: continue`` and that occurs to be the same issue as the edited question I have posted (The outprint)

Comment: If you do that, then you are again *not printing anything!*. Please **do as I say**. Change `logger.debug` to `logger.info`.

Comment: @Booboo Just edited the post again, It looks like you are a magician or so! Now it seems that its "randomly" (which might is not randomly) between the threads, as you can see its switches between the 0-4 threads which is nice! But I guess if I want to do some sort of FIFO then I would need to do totally new approach with the threads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234613/discussion-between-booboo-and-protractornewbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In general* the same proxy could be handed out twice in succession.

Just to make sure that the same proxy is not being given out twice in succession in *your case*, modify `QueuePut` **just for debugging purposes**. But if you get no assertion error, then revert the code back to your original class definition.

```python
class QueuePut(contextlib.AbstractContextManager):
    from threading import Lock
    lock = Lock()
    last_proxy_obtained = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.proxy = proxy_q.get(block=True)
        with self.lock:
            assert(self.proxy != self.last_proxy_obtained)
            self.last_proxy_obtained = self.proxy
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, excType, excValue, traceback):
        proxy_q.put(self.proxy)
```

The above code assumes that the the thread that successfully executes `self.proxy = proxy_q.get(block=True)` will then not be suspended but able to immediately execute the following `with self.lock:` statement. If that assumption fails, then you could potentially get an assertion error even though the program is working correctly. So if you do get an assertion error, you should then rerun with the following version, which only allows one thread at a time to be requesting a proxy:

```python
class QueuePut(contextlib.AbstractContextManager):
    from threading import Lock
    lock = Lock()
    last_proxy_obtained = None

    def __enter__(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.proxy = proxy_q.get(block=True)
            assert(self.proxy != self.last_proxy_obtained)
            self.last_proxy_obtained = self.proxy
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, excType, excValue, traceback):
        proxy_q.put(self.proxy)
```

**Testing Program**

In the following program, however, I would not expect the same proxy to be handed out twice in succession:

```python
import contextlib
import queue
from threading import Thread

list_op_proxy = [
    "http://test.io:12345",
    "http://test.io:123456",
]

proxy_q = queue.Queue()

for i in list_op_proxy:
    proxy_q.put(i)


class QueuePut(contextlib.AbstractContextManager):
    from threading import Lock
    lock = Lock()
    last_proxy_obtained = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.proxy = proxy_q.get(block=True)
        with self.lock:
            assert(self.proxy != self.last_proxy_obtained)
            self.last_proxy_obtained = self.proxy
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, excType, excValue, traceback):
        proxy_q.put(self.proxy)


def handler(name):
    for i in range(100):
        with QueuePut() as proxy:
            print(f"{name} | Proxy in use: {proxy}", flush=True)

for i in range(5):
    Thread(target=handler, args=(f'Thread {i}',)).start()
```